# Xamarin Forms Android - keyboard input going to page behind

Tags: android, forms, xamarin

I've got a strange issue where when I'm on a page (Page 1) that has an Entry, I tap the Entry to give it focus, then I tap a button that calls Navigation.PushModalAsync to bring up another page (Page 2) which only has a Label on it, I type on the physical keyboard, then hit back to go back to Page 1, I magically find the text I'd typed when on Page 2 is in the Entry on Page 1!

That feels like a bug to me? How can I stop keyboard entry going to Page 1 when Page 2 is displayed?

I'm using VS2022, Xamarin Forms 5.0.0.2196, and an Android Emulator using Android 9 / API 29.

```
    public class Page1 : ContentPage
    {

        public Page1()
        {
            StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout();
            stackLayout.Children.Add(new Label() { Text = "Page 1. Tap in Entry A, and then tap the Click Me button." });
            stackLayout.Children.Add(new Entry() { Placeholder = "Entry A" });
            Button button = new Button() { Text = "Click Me" };
            stackLayout.Children.Add(button);
            Content = stackLayout;
            button.Clicked += Button_Clicked;
        }

        private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ContentPage page2 = new ContentPage();
            page2.Content = new Label() { Text = "Page 2. Type some letters on the physical keyboard, and then hit the Back button to get back to Page 1." };
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(page2));
        }
    }
```

Comment: The entry from Page1 is still focused try setting the entry as a variable on the page and call `entry.Unfocus()` when page2 is pushed.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the reply. I have tried that and alas it makes no difference :(

Comment: You may have to make the UnFocus call on the MainThread/UIThread assuming it's not bound to anything in a ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

I had test your code on different versions of Android. And at first, when you tap the button, the Entry should be unfocused. Because if I tapped the Entry and then tapped the other field, the cursor will disappear from the Entry. But when I typed on the physical keyboard, the soft keyboard will appear and the text I'd typed will show on the Entry on the Android 9.0.

On the Android 10.0, the soft keyboard will appear but the text will not show on the Entry.

On the Android 11.0, both the keyboard and the text don't show.

In addition, on the Android 9.0, if you don't have tapped the Entry at first, the soft keyboard and the text will not show when you typed on the physical keyboard.

So, this should be the different handling of physical input events in Xamarin.Forms in different Android version. You can also post the issue to the [Xamarin.Forms](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues) to get the answer.